# How do I dynamically number widgets as they are created on a WordPress page?

Tags: php, wordpress, siteorigin

The WordPress website that I am creating has an Frequently Asked Questions page. Each question/answer pair is created via use of the [SiteOrigin Page Builder Plugin](https://siteorigin.com/page-builder/) and a custom widget. I would like to be able to add new questions and rearrange them without needing to manually renumber.

This is how it looks right now:

[image: SiteOrigin Page Builder View]

I would simply like the questions to be dynamically numbered (1., 2., 3., and soforth, just before the question).

I can think of some hack-ish ways that might accomplish this task, like abusing an `<ol>` tag or global variable. I might also be able to use some code to count the number of elements that have been created with the class "question", but it feels like that would add unnecessary code/latency to what should possible with a simple integer variable that exists only while this page is being rendered.

Is possible in WordPress? If so, how do I accomplish it? If not, is there a better method than what I have mentioned?

If it helps, here's the render code from my widget's PHP file:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance )
{
    $question = $instance['question'];
    $answer = $instance['answer'];

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( ! empty( $question ) )
    {
        echo '<h3 class="question">';
        echo '. ';
        echo $question;
        echo '</h3>';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $answer ) )
    {
        echo '<p>';
        echo $answer;
        echo '</p>';
    }

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

Comment: Hi! What are the numbers for? Do they need to be sequential? Or represent an order on the page? Or you just want each widget to have a unique ID?

Comment: @MacPrawn I just want them to be ordered 1. 2. 3. and soforth so that it is easy to locate and refer to the questions. I will update the post so that this is more clear.

Comment: Oh, ok, and why would <ol> be abusive? Seems like the perfect use-case for it?

Comment: I feel like nesting <h3> and <p> tags inside of an <ol><li> isn't really what it is intended for, but I could very well be wrong. I threw together some code quickly and it doesn't actually look that bad: https://jsfiddle.net/zhtxtz72/

Comment: Ah ok - well, depending on which browsers you want to support, you could do it in css: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-reset/... Otherwise, some javascript could also do the trick. Or server-side, as you suggested, a class variable or something like that.

Comment: the solution would be quite complex to do, usually with wordpress the key is identifying the hooks or filters if there is. Usually not documented and you have to search into your pagebuilder code. But if you find it, you can use the hook in functions.php to count the rows on their create hook, or a filter even

Comment: They actually have a fair bit of documentation on their [hooks and filters](https://siteorigin.com/docs/widgets-bundle/advanced-concepts/hooks-and-filters/) but I can't seem to find a good place where I could put this code. A lot of it seems to executed individually for each widget to be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this, but I ended up using [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) (which I was already using for other things) to store/set a variable. After setting up an integer variable in ACF, I did the following (in my Widget PHP file):

```
public function widget( $args, $instance )
{
    $question = $instance['question'];
    $answer = $instance['answer'];

    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( ! empty( $question ) )
    {
        echo '<h3 class="question">';
        $question_count = (int) get_field('question_count');
        $question_count++;
        update_field('question_count', $question_count);
        echo $question_count;
        echo '. ';
        echo $question;
        echo '</h3>';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $answer ) )
    {
        echo '<p>';
        echo $answer;
        echo '</p>';
    }

    echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

I'm going to leave the post up for a couple of days to see if anyone comes up with a better answer without the use of ACF, in case someone down the road has a different use-case than I do.